# Can you use bit shift operations in a 'for-loop'?

Tags: python

I have the following C for loop using bit shifts, that I want to reimplement in python.

```
n = 64
for(int stride = n>>1; stride >0; stride >>=1)
   {...
```

**So wow would this loop look in python?**

I know that `n>>1` stands for division by 2, but I find it hard to model that with `range()`.

Comment: I think you have an error in your C code. That loop is never-ending as ``stride`` will never drop below zero, but the loop won't quit until it does...

Comment: @Blair, you are right, I minimalized my example to much. I will correct it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `for(;;)` loops can be rewritten as `while` loops, and vice versa.

```
n = 64
stride = n >> 1
while stride > 0:
    # stuff
    stride >>= 1
```

**EDITED** to reflect the change in the original

Comment: This matches what the original code in the question does i.e., an endless loop. *Caveat emptor*...

Comment: Indeed it does. I was just showing the general rewriting method (i.e. syntactic equivalence), completely disregarding semantics.

Comment: @Amadan, I have changed the original condition from >=0 to >0

Comment: @Amadan - yeah, I realised that. I was just adding a note for future readers to make sure they were aware of this.

Answer (score 5):

Think simpler:

```
>>> n = 64
>>> while n:
...     print n
...     n = n >> 1
...
64
32
16
8
4
2
1
```

Answer (score 5):

[Amadan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6745651/78845) is spot on.

If you use this pattern a lot, I'd extract this into a simple generator function to be reused in `for`-loops:

```
>>> def strider(n):
...     stride = n >> 1
...     while stride > 0:
...         yield stride
...         stride >>= 1
...
>>> for n in strider(64):
...     print n
...
32
16
8
4
2
1
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind is:

```
while stride>0:
   # do your stuff
   stride>>=1
```

I don't think it is a good idea to try and use for-loops in this case. In Python for-loops work much like for-each loops in other languages. They act on sequences. Although we could easily turn the range of values for stride into a sequence, the `while` IMHO is a much simpler and more natural way of expressing the idea.

Comment: This matches what the original code in the question does i.e., an endless loop. *Caveat emptor*...

Comment: @Blair: I completely missed that error myself. Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own [generator](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html#generators) for use in the for loop

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not have many iterations:

```
for stride in [32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1, 0]:
  # ...
```

Comment: I see but how many consecutive shifts can a C integer dure anyway? :)

Comment: @junjanes - on my machine, 64 (using the ``long long`` data type). A little unwieldy to write out like you suggest. Plus it is only good for fixed starting values (i.e., if the initial value of n depends on some other code, your solution won't adapt very well).

Answer (score -1):

How about using a logarithm?

```
for i in range(int(math.log(n, 2)), -1, -1):
    # stride is 2**i
```

Comment: But this won't divide i by 2 in every step, will it?

Comment: That gives me `(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.

Comment: @Tim: Fixed to make it so that you can easily calculate `stride`.

Comment: Nice idea, doesn't seem particularly easy to read or efficient though... :)

Answer (score -2):

Well, closest is to use [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile, imap, count
>>> n = 64
>>> for i in takewhile(bool, imap(lambda x:n >> x, count(1))):
...     print i
... 
32
16
8
4
2
1
```